# R Apply() function instead of a loop requiring the index of the values

Tags: r

I use a for loop (which works well) to replace randomly two values in each line of a dataset by NA (the indexes of this values are randomly changes at each line).
Now I would like to use apply() to do exactly the same thing.
I tried this code (as many other things which return NA everywhere):

```
my_fun<-function(x){if (j %in% sample(1:ncol(y),2)) {x[j]<-NA}}
apply(y,1,my_fun)
```

But it doesn't work (it does not make any change to the initial dataset).
The problem is that the object `j` is not found.  j should be the number of the column.
Does someone have an idea?

Comment: You have to return `x` from your function. In a call of a function the arguments are given to the function per **call by value**

Comment: thank you but the problem here is that the object j is not found

Comment: What object is `y`? Please use `dput()` to present your data! If `y` is a matrix (or a data.frame) then `apply(y, 1, my_fun)` is sending row by row to your function `my_fun`. So in your function `my_fun` the object `x` is a vector (i.e. one row from `y`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I argue that you want:

```
my_fun <- function(x) { x[sample(1:length(x), 2)] <- NA; x }
apply(y, 1, my_fun) # or
t(apply(y, 1, my_fun))
```

Testing the function:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- matrix(1:60, 10)
y
t(apply(y, 1, my_fun))
# > t(apply(y, 1, my_fun))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1   11   21   31   NA   NA
# [2,]    2   NA   22   32   NA   52
# [3,]    3   13   NA   NA   43   53
# [4,]   NA   14   24   34   NA   54
# [5,]    5   15   25   NA   45   NA
# [6,]    6   16   NA   NA   46   56
# [7,]    7   NA   27   37   47   NA
# [8,]    8   18   NA   38   NA   58
# [9,]   NA   19   29   39   49   NA
# [10,]  10   20   NA   40   50   NA
```

Comment: but now I have a new problem, as one of my variable is of character type, after using the function apply, all my numeric values are changed in character type and I really need them to keep their original type...

Comment: y is a dataframe with character and numerical columns and I would like to have random NA whatever the column type

Comment: The new problem is not part of your question. `n <- sapply(y, is.numeric); y <- as.data.frame(t(apply(y, 1, my_fun))); y[n] <- lapply(y[n], as.numeric)`